# Combobox value is not selected by ZipFile compression

Tags: c#, zip

I am Creating Windows Application.I am using `FolderBrowserDialog textBox1 ComboBox` and button. In my button click I want to select a combo box value and store in a zip file. But it is not accepting combo box value and showing me error. Any idea how to resolve?

```
namespace WinDataStore
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ComboBox comboBox;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
          var daysOfWeek = new[] { "RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"};

            // Initialize combo box
            comboBox = new ComboBox
            {
                DataSource = daysOfWeek,
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 140),
                Name = "comboBox",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(166, 21),
                DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
            };

            // Add the combo box to the form.
            this.Controls.Add(comboBox);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderBrowserDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;         
            DialogResult dlgResult = folderBrowserDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (dlgResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
            {                
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDlg.SelectedPath;              
               Environment.SpecialFolder rootFolder = folderBrowserDlg.RootFolder;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var comboBox = this.Controls["comboBox"] as ComboBox;

            string s = (string)comboBox.SelectedItem;

            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.AddFile("s", "files");

                zip.Save("z.zip");
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"and showing me error"` - So here's the obvious question... *What is the error?*

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment above:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException

[The `.Add()` method](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/202e1fb5-8891-888f-8e91-1340f7cd80c9.htm) that you're using expects a file name:

```
zip.AddFile("s", "files");
```

Do you really have a file that's just named `"s"` in the current working directory?  The runtime is telling you that you don't.  And I'm inclined to believe it.  You can't add a file which doesn't exist.

You *do* have a *string variable* called `s`:

```
string s = (string)comboBox.SelectedItem;
```

Maybe you meant to use that?:

```
zip.AddFile(s, "files");
```